# Fairly new position as an I.T. contractor & client is assigning tasks outside scope of contract

Tags: united-states

I have a fairly new position as an I.T. contractor. I was hired along with a small group of people at the same time to work on a project. I've never held a contract position before. It's a W2/full-time position.

The client has assigned tasks to me that really don’t have anything to do with my current contract or title (whole reason I’m there.) No one else in my newly-hired group got this other role. I have agreed to learn these new items because of the experience and knowledge I would gain. The client's employees keep calling this "promotions". Like I earned it and they even say I'm trusted.

I’ve advised the company that I work for about the assignments that are in addition to and alongside the original assignment. I have also self-trained on everything given to me. All others in my group have received training. I am self-training and keep being told that training is coming (on both roles essentially.)

Given that my review is very soon, I notified my company that I work for about the additional role and the self-training; they didn’t seem to care that I was doing extra assignments given by the client nor were they already aware (I had a feeling they did not know).

1. Can I or will I mostly likely receive a raise at review time for basically doing two jobs (and self-training)?
2. If my company refuses to give me a raise at the time of my review, can I tell the client that I’m not getting paid for the additional role and decline to work on it anymore?
3. Can I lose my job if I decline to do the items outside of my contract/title?
4. Do clients often give assignments outside of your contract? I could have turned it down before, but I thought the experience and knowledge would be a good thing. I also thought I would get a raise. I thought it was a no-brainer. Now I feel like I've inadvertently dug myself into a hole.

Comment: I thought a w2 was effectively an employee and not an independant contractor? So effectively you do what your employer asks you

Comment: Since this is new to me, let me explain that this way, myself and my group hired for the project are called "permanent" full-time employees with the company we work for even though the contract with the client is year-to-year. We are full-time employees with the computer science company with benefits, etc.

Comment: so your an employee your employer can direct you as they like

Comment: the employer can (computer science company) however, I/we work onsite for a client and we all have contracts with certain titles.

Comment: So do _you_ have a contract with the client organization, or does _your employer_ hold the contract?  If you _personally_ have a contract with the client, check what it says.  If you have no such contract, it's really up to your employer.

Comment: The contract I hold is with the computer science company (my employer). The client agreed to my/our contract(s).

Comment: @firepro1111 - In that case it sounds like you have little recourse.  The agreement is actually between your employer and the client.  That likely means your employer gets to decide on issues like this.  And it sounds like they've decided that they're happy for the client to assign you the extra role.

Comment: @AROTH So, in turn, I'm doing extra work, self-training and continuously going above and beyond and they don't have to (and mostly likely won't) give me a raise at all?

Comment: @firepro1111 - That's the impression that I get, yes.

Answer (score 2):

So the way I understand your role: You work for organization A which provides you with full-time benefits, but you are now being contracted out to company B for a project, correct? I hope so because here is my answer:

1. **Can I or will I mostly likely receive a raise at review time for basically doing two jobs (and self-training)?** I wouldn’t hold my breath. Chances are you are being treated as a full-time staffer by your contractor simply because they want you to work more. Meaning, they want to get the most out of their contract even if it is out of scope.
2. **If my company refuses to give me a raise at the time of my review, can I tell the client that I’m not getting paid for the additional role and decline to work on it anymore?** That would seem to be a reasonable response, but the stilted reporting structure seems to imply that this is something your direct supervisor at true main company should do & not you. Meaning, you go for a review, explain what happened, wait for a response. If you get a raise, great! But be sure to place some controls/limits so you don’t end up doing even more “new” out of scope work in the future without the risk of not getting a raise. And if you don’t get a raise, you need to clearly state that if that is the case, why would you be doing additional work? Be as polite & professional about this but be firm about it: You are not doing work for your health. It’s a job. If there is no clear reward for extra work, why do it?
3. **Can I lose my job if I decline to do the items outside of my contract/title?** Possibly. But unclear. Look at my response for item two. Have a real discussion with your employers about this situation & do it professionally. Clearly state you want to do new & exciting things, but if there is no career growth path, why bother?
4. **Do clients often give assignments outside of your contract? I could have turned it down before, but I thought the experience and knowledge would be a good thing. I also thought I would get a raise. I thought it was a no-brainer. Now I feel like I've inadvertently dug myself into a hole.** I want to say that this is unique & unusual, but the reality is not just in the world of tech—but life in general—if you give an inch, chances are some people will take a mile. It stinks, but in the case of tech work it is a bit worse because everyone knows that somehow the world we work in is filled with exploration & curiosity. So us techs naturally become “suckers” for stuff like this. So be sure to set some clear boundaries. Because the reality is the less boundaries you have to your work, the more you will be taken advantage of. I’ve been doing this type of work for 20+ years and it’s taken me nearly that long to realize the harder you work to set boundaries at the outset, the better your situation will be in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Can I or will I mostly likely receive a raise?**  It depends.  I'd say it's an unlikely prospect, however.  At least in terms of receiving a raise for the 'extra' work that you're doing.  Which as you said, your primary employer doesn't even seem to know or care about.

   The most likely outcome is that you will receive a comparable raise to everyone else.
2. **Can I decline to work [the second role] anymore?** You *can* do that at any time, for any reason.  That doesn't mean that it would be a wise move, however.  And since your *employer* would be the one who refused you the raise in that case, it would be more appropriate to take it up with them rather than to create friction with the client (which your employer will not appreciate if/when they learn of it).

   Let them know that you feel that the extra role you've been filling warrants extra compensation, and that if they're not willing to provide it then you're not willing to fill two roles at the same time any longer, and that *they* should inform the client that the client can no longer utilize you in that capacity.
3. **Can I lose my job [for declining the second role]?**  Almost certainly yes, that's something that *can* happen.  Generally speaking you can lose your job for virtually any reason.  If there are any specific limitations on that, they'd be in 1) your contract with your employer and 2) your local employment laws.  So those are worth checking.  It sounds like you're in the U.S., however, so I'd be surprised if your employment was anything other than "at will".
4. **Do clients often give assignments outside of your contract?** Most clients will try to get away with as much as they can.  Extra assignments, scope creep, free maintenance and upgrades, you name it.  It's up to the contract holder to decide how they want to handle those cases.

   Based on my understanding, however, your *employer* is the contract holder, rather than you yourself.  So it's not clear if the client has gone outside of the scope of the contract they hold with your employer.  And even if they have, it sounds like your employer has decided that they are okay with it.

As far as a practical solution goes, it sounds like you're actually learning some valuable new skills.  And getting paid to do so.  That's not something that needs to be seen as a negative.

Perhaps you're unhappy with the additional workload at no additional pay, or the client's behavior in general.  You can bring that up with your employer in the context of requesting a raise (or that they bring the client in line).  However, some of that just comes with the territory when IT contracting.  If you'd like to get away from that sort of thing, consider updating your resume with your new skills and seeking out a position further outside of the contracting space.

If you like software development but don't like dealing with external clients and their unreasonable demands, consider applying for a first-party dev position somewhere.  Pretty much all of the major players are constantly hiring, and there's no shortage of new minor players if the idea of jumping into a startup appeals to you.

Comment: That's been my experience. Being able to learn new skills as a contractor is a great way to push my rate up, but when hired as you are I found I could only do that by changing jobs. I did the contractor-on-a-salary thing once, for ~9 months, then switched to directly contracting. To benefit from your situation you really need to negotiate aggressively when you're hired by your employer, or when the client asked you to do something new. Not after you've done it...

Answer (score 0):

The trick to contracting is, in my mind, figuring out how long a particular project is going to take and then, after advising your client of this, delivering the goods within the timeframe expected. If a company lays additional responsibilities on you, I don't think that the proper answer is to balk and refuse, it's to take them on, advising them all the way that you will need extra time to complete stuff, whether that extra time comes in the form of literally needing longer than, say, the 3 months they gave you on the contract, or in the form of overtime (many clients don't want to pay for overtime except under dire circumstances because in addition to paying you time and a half, they're usually paying your contractor an extra premium as well for the added work).

On the other hand, if you were really only putting in 20 hours of work a week before this, or if you were going to finish ahead of schedule, I think it's okay to let them know this as well and just take on the extra work. In the end, the client views you as a resource rather than one of their own employees. This has the advantage, in many cases, that they will actually be *more* reticent to exploit you unfairly (i.e. trying to get you to work overtime off the clock) because you don't actually work for them. It's also my experience (which may not be yours in this particular situation) that often the people who hired you are not as informed about the technology you support as you are and as such trust you when you tell them what impact an added responsibility will have upon your work.

The flip side of that is, if you are giving them 40 hours a week plus overtime, they kind of do get to ask/tell you how to spend those 40 hours. I mean, I'm not generally going to do data entry for 80 hours over two weeks but the way I'm going to express that is "you're paying me quite a bit of money to do something that's outside of my area of expertise; are you sure that's the best use of my time?" rather than "no, I can't do that". You also don't really get to say "hey, you hired me to be an admin, and if you want me to develop stuff too (for example) I will need X more money". You were hired on by the company because, in the words of Liam Neeson, you have a particular set of skills.

I would go so far as to say that the difference between a bad contractor and a good one is that, when asked if something can be done, the former will say "no" and the latter will say "yes, but it will take X amount of additional time", or, at worst, "yes, but I am not familiar with the technology required to do this so it will take X amount of time for me to ramp myself up to where I will have that familiarity and Y amount to then actually do the work". You've already done around half of what a good contractor does, which is to never flat-out say "no", now you just need to follow through on the second part if necessary.

Answering your questions in specific:

1. **Can I or will I mostly likely receive a raise at review time for basically doing two jobs (and self-training)?** Probably not, no. I've worked jobs which were originally straight-up administration-based but which ended up having a development component when the client learned of my prior experience. This is called adding value, and I don't think it's wise to get into the mindset that every time you do that it has to cost somebody.
2. **If my company refuses to give me a raise at the time of my review, can I tell the client that I’m not getting paid for the additional role and decline to work on it anymore?** That's a really, really bad idea in my experience. What you ought to be doing whether you end up keeping the same role or not is properly billing for your work. If you have two duties which both take up 25 hours of your time a week and this does in fact cause you to work a total of 50 hours, you need to bill 50 and take the overtime. Conversely, if you estimated that you would be finished on a job in six weeks based on being able to commit 40 hours a week to something and now this company wants you to split your time on something else, you need to advise them (ideally at the moment that they ask you to take on the additional responsibilities so that they can make an informed decision) how much more time you will require to finish the project.
3. **Can I lose my job if I decline to do the items outside of my contract/title?** What do you think the answer to this question is? Unless you're being asked to do something that's against the law, what you're talking about doing has a name: insubordination. People get fired for insubordination all the time. Additionally, it's my experience that contract agencies tend to give you a *very* short leash when it comes to turning down jobs like that. If you don't want to work on a particular technology, don't mention that you know how to do it to clients.
4. **Do clients often give assignments outside of your contract? I could have turned it down before, but I thought the experience and knowledge would be a good thing. I also thought I would get a raise. I thought it was a no-brainer. Now I feel like I've inadvertently dug myself into a hole.** Getting additional requirements and wearing additional hats is a common side effect of contracting, absolutely. Even if you're on a job in which you end up doing only things that are particularly within your "wheelhouse" of expertise, sometimes a business's internal rules will require you to do things in a very specific way that takes longer than a well-worn, easier path. I also find that every business has a different set of rules and therefore every challenge will be different.

Contracting is a lot of fun in my experience - you get to meet a lot of interesting people, you don't stay on any one job long enough to get bored doing it, and usually at the end of the day you've got an actual working product that you can look back on with satisfaction. Often, companies will hire out a contractor with the thought that if the person performs well, they'll extend an offer to them, which can be a nice experience - even if you turn them down, the fact that you are valued that much by a client can be enough to motivate your contractor to get you that raise you were looking for. Even if they don't, sometimes a good performance in one contract leads to another, similar job for the same client. And sometimes, if you don't like the working conditions, the nature of the contract allows you to walk away at the end of it with no bridges burned and no offense being raised.

You have to come in with the right mindset, however. Contracting is not the same thing as actually working for the client. It takes some getting used to but more than anything else it takes the proper attitude to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slippery slope.  Contractor job duties change a lot in the IT world.  If you're learning new skills and technologies that is huge.  It will benefit you later. Honest.  Contractors that get the best rates go the extra mile with a great attitude-always. They also will extend for years, get the sibling to move to different assignments with their contracting firm and sometimes get hired by the client company. Realize that contractors vs "employees" in the IT world is usually a budget thing (do they have perm head count budget or business unit expense budget for this work?) not a work content thing.  Just like full time company employees, you do what is expected for the results that your manager needs.
You discuss pay only with your employer. Your employer is NOT the company who you are performing work for. Your employer is where your paycheck comes from and sharing that employee specific detail to their client is prohibited (it was probably in your worker handbook you signed ) and unprofessional.   If you have been on the project for a while (6 to 12 months) discussing details with your employer would be beneficial.  Depending of their policies and employee review schedule, you may or may not get an increase.  They will know, though, that they may want to have a discussion soon with their client regarding changes in skill level required by their project.